# Javascript is not running when I change my popup's html in a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I have a popup that runs a javascript on document ready and redirects changing the popup.html for another... This is the manifiest

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "My App",
"description": "Lorem ipsum",
"version": "1.0",
"background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js", "background/background.js"]
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["*"],
        "js": ["js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js", "content/buttons.js"]
    }
],
"web_accessible_resources": ["content/*.html"],
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "favicon-96x96.png",
    "default_popup": "popup/index/index.html"
},
"permissions": [
    "tabs", "webNavigation", "notifications", "*://localhost/*",        "http://127.0.0.1/*"
    ]
}
```

the popup.js

```
//Some code that runs correctly
chrome.browserAction.setPopup("list/list.html");
```

my list.html renders on the popup without any problem and it looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"     href="../../css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../main.css">
<title>TaskCrusher</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MyApp</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling     -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a class="logout-button" href="#" onclick="return logOut();">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<h4>Welcome!</h4>



</body>
<script src="../../js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="../../js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="../global.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="../../js/carhartl-jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="../../js/notifyjs/notify.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="list.js"></script>
</html>
```

As you see, at the end I insert list.js but no matter what I do this doesn't run when list.html is loading...

I checked everywhere but I don't se where the error could be.

This is the list.js

```
var checkCardWaiting = function() {
var card = $.cookie('card');
if (card) {
    // There was a card waiting
    redirect("post/post.html");
}
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    checkCardWaiting();
});
```

I tried with $(checkCardWaiting) and $(document).ready(checkCardWaiting) but when I debug I see that it doesn't even run the code. Also, when I debug I see the js file downloaded in the source tab.

Thank you a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. Actually it was running. I thought it wasn't because I was using chrome debugger on the popup and it didn't stop in any breakpoint. But I put a console.log commands and they did run. After trying all over without reloading the extension, I saw that the third time I run the code the debugger starts stopping in the breakpoints... so it was a debugger problem.